# Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized when using Rackspace cloud via league/flysystem-rackspace

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have an PHP Laravel application that's a couple of years old now. It uploads files to the Rackspace cloud using the package league/flysystem-rackspace which is installed via composer.

Lately I'm seeing the following error when trying to upload files;

```
CurlException in CurlMulti.php line 338:
[curl] 60: Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized. [url] https://identity.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2.0/tokens
```

Why is this happening and how can I resolve it?

I've tried to remove the vendor folder and run composer install, but the server is currently running an old version of PHP 5.6 and composer complains about packages requiring PHP 7.

Would upgrading to PHP 7 and updating all packages fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up spooling up a new VM running Ubuntu 18.04, moving my application over to the new server and allowing composing install to update the project dependencies. This resolved the issue.

The old VM was running Centos 6 and PHP 5.6, which is what was causing the problem.